# why is my collider is not triggering when i attack?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, I did everything like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iYWpzL9GkM but when the sword collider activates the slime doesn't disappear, for some reason the colliders don't interact even if I turn on the slime collider trigger.

1:23:40 like that

enemy code

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Enemy enemy;

   
    public float health = 1;

    public float maxhealth = 1;

    public void Start()
    {
        health = maxhealth;
    }
    public float Health
    {

        set
        {

            health = value;
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                TakeDamage();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return health;
        }
    }
    public void TakeDamage()
    {

        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
```

sword code

```
public class swordattack : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Collider2D swordcollider;

    public float damage = 3;
    
    Vector2 rightattackoff;
    private void Start()
    {
        
        rightattackoff = transform.position;
    }

    
    public void AttackRight()
    {
        
        swordcollider.enabled = true;
        transform.localPosition = rightattackoff;

    }

    public void AttackLeft()
    {
        swordcollider.enabled = true;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(rightattackoff.x * -1, rightattackoff.y);

    }

    public void StopAttack()
    {
        swordcollider.enabled = false;

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("afsafhagfagjksdjg");
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Enemy enemy = other.GetComponent<Enemy>();

            if(enemy != null)
            {

                enemy.Health -= damage;
            }

        }

    }
```

character code

```
public class playercontrol : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed = 1f;

    public float collisionOffset = 0.05f;

    public ContactFilter2D movementFilter;

    public swordattack swordAttack;

    Vector2 movementInput;

    Rigidbody2D rig;

    List<RaycastHit2D> castCollisions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    Animator animator;

    SpriteRenderer spRen;

    bool canMove = true;

    


    void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        spRen = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            if (movementInput != Vector2.zero)
            {
                bool success = TryMove(movementInput);
                if (!success)
                {
                    success = TryMove(new Vector2(movementInput.x, 0));

                    if (!success)
                    {

                        success = TryMove(new Vector2(0, movementInput.y));
                    }
                }

                animator.SetBool("isMoving", success);
            }
            else
            {
                animator.SetBool("isMoving", false);
            }

            if (movementInput.x < 0)
            {
                spRen.flipX = true;
               
            }
            else if (movementInput.x > 0)
            {
                spRen.flipX = false;
                
            }
        }
    }


    private bool TryMove(Vector2 direction)
    {

        int count = rig.Cast(
                direction,
                movementFilter,
                castCollisions,
                moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            rig.MovePosition(rig.position + direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }

    void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
    {
        movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();

    }

    void OnFire()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("swordAttack");

    }


    public void SwordAttack()
    {

        LockMovement();
        if (spRen.flipX == true)
        {
            swordAttack.AttackLeft();

        }

        else
        {
            swordAttack.AttackRight();
        }
    }
   public void EndSwordAttack()
    {
        UnlockMovement();
        swordAttack.StopAttack();
       
    }

    void LockMovement()
    {
        canMove = false;
    }
    void UnlockMovement()
    {
        canMove = true;
}
     

}
```

If everything was working correctly, the sword collider would activate when clicked and then by hitting the slime the object should disappear

Comment: well other than you missed something... did you set the collider as trigger? is there a rigid body somewhere? did you meet the conditions of the collision?

Comment: I tried turning the trigger on and off and it still didn’t work, there is a rigidbody 2D on the character, but I don’t know the conditions, I just repeated everything that was in the video and it still doesn’t work

Comment: Sadly, you missed something. and you need to rewatch the video

Comment: yes, it turns out I didn’t have Rigidbody 2D for the slimes, but a new problem appeared: when I start the game, all the slimes disappear, and nothing is written in the console

Comment: not everything needs a rigid body, however,  you need to understand the collision matrix to make things work.

Comment: it finally worked! It turns out that I turned off the collider for my character, so the objects were not destroyed, although the slimes still disappear, but other enemies are destroyed normally

Comment: I understood the problem, the slimes did not disappear but fell very quickly, because Rigidbody 2D was dynamic, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking for a collision between the Sword and the Slime, one of the two needs to have a Rigidbody (or Rigidbody2D) attached to it for the collision to trigger.

Comment: i have a rigidbody 2D on my character

Comment: For some reason, the enemy disappears only when the collider is always on, but if I turn it off and make it turn on and off when pressed, then nothing happens